# ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado - Ajuda

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle10g

Estou tentanto criar a seguinte tabela no SQL

```
create table Compra 
(
    CodCompra number(3) primary key, 
    DataCompra date, 
    DataEntrega date,
    Fornecedor foreign key Fornecedor REFERENCES (codfornecedor)Fornecedor
)
```

> ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado

Quando se remove o "`Fornecedor foreign key Fornecedor REFERENCES (codfornecedor)Fornecedor`" a tabela é criada normalmente. E ao dar o comando

```
alter table Compra
add foreign key (Fornecedor) references Fornecedor (Fornecedor)
```

Ele caracteriza `Fornecer` como identificador inválido.

**Obs.**: Ja foi criada a tabela `FORNECEDOR` com chave primária `CodFornecedor`.

Answer (score 2):

Faça uma pequena alteração nesse trecho

```
Fornecedor foreign key Fornecedor REFERENCES (codfornecedor)Fornecedor
```

Altere para isso

```
FornecedorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Fornecedor(codfornecedor)
```

**Fornecedor** vai ser uma coluna na tabela **Compra**, por isso mude o nome para **FornecedorID**, é um padrão de banco de dados. Outra coisa que faltou foi dizer o tipo do campo, no caso **int** e por último, informe o nome da tabela que está sendo referenciada antes do campo, com isso creio que seu comando vai ser executado

O comando completo seria esse

```
CREATE TABLE Compra (
  CodCompra number(3) PRIMARY KEY, 
  DataCompra date, 
  DataEntrega date, 
  FornecedorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Fornecedor(codfornecedor) 
);
```

Verifique se a coluna **codfornecedor** está escrito assim na sua tabela de **Fornecedor**

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!